# how to dispay value in laravel pages

Tags: php, laravel-4

hello every one i am new in laravel i try to pass value in to view folder this is my controller code in `echo "<pre>"; print_r($user);` i getting the all database value

```
public function index()
{
    $user = Userregistration::all()->username;
    //echo "<pre>"; print_r($user);
    return View::make('userregistrations.index', compact('user'));
}
```

but problem is that i send the value to View/user/index.blade.php their is no value getting me and i don't know to fetch value their my index.blade.php page code is
 `{{{ $user }}}`

please help me how to find this problem

Comment: `return View::make('userregistrations.index', $user);`

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate through the collection to print out each of the values.

```
@foreach ($user as $username)
    {{{ $username }}}
@endforeach
```

If this doesnt work, try;

```
$user = Userregistration::get('username');
```

And then iterate through the results on the page.

Comment: Dont forget to mark as answer kind sir, @user3825129